# Servlet Hello World Error - Root cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am reading another amazing *Head First* book. This one is, "Head First Servlets & JSP - Passing the Sun Certified Web Component Developer Exam". I am following along with the first tutorial on creating a small "hello world" type of program. This is on pages 30 to 31.

I am compiling the Java source code in the following way:
`C:\Users\username\Desktop\Servlets_HF_Example\project1>javac -classpath C:\tomcat\
apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26\lib\servlet-api.jar
 -d classes src/Ch1Servlet.java`

The class that is not found, the cause of the 500 error, has the following source code:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        out.println("<html> " + 
                    "<body> " + " <h1 align=center>Head First Chapter 1 Servlet</h1>"
                    + "<br>" + today + "</body> " + "</html>");

    }


}
```

The web.xml file has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have the following folder structure for the code:

```
 project1
        |
        |
       +classes
          | 
          Ch1Servlet.class
       +etc
          |
          web.xml
       +src
          |
          Ch1Servlet.java
```

The project structure that is put into the tomcat webapps directory is as follows:

```
   ch1
     |
     |
     +classes
         |
         Ch1Servlet.class
     +WEB-INF
         |
         web.xml
```

[image]
Figure 0: Folder structure of deployed project

I have my TOMCAT_HOME directory set and JAVA_HOME set on this Windows 7 operating-system (OS). When I deploy the application and startup Tomcat 1) I see a 500 error saying that the class is not found. This is the Ch1Servlet.class that is not found. Then if I refresh the page I see 2) a 404 error. These errors are shown below.

[image]
Figure 1: 500 Error - 1st click

[image]
Figure 2: 404 - 2nd click

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your classes to be loaded properly by the application server, the structure of your webapp should be the following:

```
ch1/
 |
 +- WEB-INF/
     |
     +- classes/
     |   |
     |   +- Ch1Servlet.class
     |
     +- web.xml
```

All classes and libraries go under the `WEB-INF` folder, specifically and respectively in `classes` and `lib`.

Comment: I actually have this folder structure. Maybe my diagram was not clear. I see that you used the plus symbol for the folder.

Comment: @user3870315 If you placed the `classes` folder under `WEB-INF`, then probably you have a different issue. You should provide more details, e.g., the content of the web.xml file and maybe some source code.

Comment: Hi Louis, sure give me an hour or so. I am busy here at work.

Comment: Louis I have put the source code up for your debugging pleasure.

Comment: @user3870315 Please check the folder structure again. I updated the structure in my answer to point out folders (which have a trailing `/`) and files. The `classes` folder should go _inside_ the `WEB-INF` folder of your webapp.

Comment: Thank-you for the help. I missed this small but crucial detail. Wow! I feel dumb again. The example works now as expected. I really really really really really really really really really appreciate the help. Learning something new is always intimidating.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit the web.xml**

```
<servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>packagenameofCh1Servlet.Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
```

```
<servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
```

``